# Remove Flicker after Splash Screen is done showing

Tags: ios, splash-screen

I have a splash screen, and I want to have it so that the very first time the user opens the app they are shown the splash screen for a little bit longer with more information, otherwise just the regular splash screen appears. I did this by just drawing the splash screen image again on top of the page they are brought to when the app first loads, then fading in the extra information, and it looks really nice, it works exactly how I wanted it to, except that when the splash screen unloads and the image I am drawing loads there is a slight flicker in between the transition and it's quite noticeable. I am wondering if there is a way to avoid this flicker and make the transition seamless so that you can't even tell you're looking at a different page.

This is my code currently, myDict is there to check if the user has opened the app at any point already:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"acctInfo.txt"];

NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

if(myDict == nil){
    int yPos = 370;
    NSString *imagePath = @"Default-568h@2x.png";
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480.0f){
        yPos = 300;
        imagePath = @"Default@2x.png";
    }
    UIImageView *splash = [self addImage:imagePath toSubview:self.view atX:0 atY:0 atWidth:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width atHeight:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_text.png"]];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(63,yPos,193,56)];
    [imageView setAlpha:0.0f];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:1.0
                          options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                          animations:^{ imageView.alpha = 1; }
                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                              [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                                    delay:1.0
                                                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                                    animations:^{ imageView.alpha = 0;
                                                                splash.alpha = 0;}
                                                    completion:^(BOOL finished){}
                              ];
                         }
         ];
}
}
```

Is there anyway to remove the flicker? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!